# working with data in tables in R

Tags: r

I'm a newbie at working with R.  I've got some data with multiple observations (i.e., rows) per subject. Each subject has a unique identifier (ID) and has another variable of interest (X) which is constant across each observation. The number of observations per subject differs.

The data might look like this:

```
ID Observation X

1      1       3

1      2       3

1      3       3

1      4       3

2      1       4

2      2       4

3      1       8

3      2       8

3      3       8
```

I'd like to find some code that would:

a) Identify the number of observations per subject

b) Identify subjects with greater than a certain number of observations (e.g., >= 15 observations)

c) For subjects with greater than a certain number of observations, I'd like to to manipulate the X value for each observation (e.g., I might want to subtract 1 from their X value, so I'd like to modify X for each observation to be X-1)

I might want to identify subjects with at least three observations and reduce their X value by 1. In the above, individuals #1 and #3 (ID) have at least three observations, and their X values--which are constant across all observations--are 3 and 8, respectively. I want to find code that would identify individuals #1 and #3 and then let me recode all of their X values into a different variable. Maybe I just want to subtract 1 from each X value. In that case, the code would then give me X values of (3-1=)2 for #1 and 7 for #3, but #2 would remain at X = 4.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry to seem like an ass, but I suggest you read a book on using **R**. It's going to be far more useful than posting numerous questions to stackoverflow. Learning the very basics of a programming language is not really the purpose of this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [aggregate function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) to do this.

a) Say your table is named temp, you can find the total number of observations for each ID and x column by using the SUM function in aggregate:

```
tot =aggregate(Observation~ID+x, temp,FUN = sum)
```

The output will look like this:

```
  ID x Observation
1  1 3          10
2  2 4           3
3  3 8           6
```

b) To see the IDs that are over a certain number, you can create a subset of the table, tot.

```
vals = tot$ID[tot$Observation>5]
```

Output is:

```
[1] 1 3
```

c) To change the values that were found in (b) you reference the subsetted data, where the number of observations is > 5, and then update those values.

```
tot$x[vals] = tot$x[vals]+1
```

The final output for the table is

```
  ID x Observation
1  1 4          10
2  2 4           3
3  3 9           6
```

To change the original table, you can subset the table by the IDs you found

```
 temp[temp$ID %in% vals,]$x = temp[temp$ID %in% vals,]$x + 1
```

Comment: This was really helpful.  However, I'd like to make changes in the X values on the original dataframe.  How might I do this?  Could I collect the indexes for the IDs I'm interested in and change the X values in the corresponding rows?

Comment: If you want to change the original table you can change the specific rows that have the same IDs like this:

`temp[temp$ID %in% vals,]$x = temp[temp$ID %in% vals,]$x + 1`

Answer (score -2):

a) Identify the number of observations per subject

you can use this code on each variable:

> summary